# Не отобразить строчки из файла

Tags: python, файлы, flask

Пытаюсь прочитать последние 3 строчки из файла, однако выдается только последняя. Не понимаю в чем загвоздка. Заранее спасибо!

```
with open("c.txt", 'r') as f:
    last3 = deque(f, 3)
    for line in last3:
            co.append(line.strip().split(','))
            for pair in co:
                x,y,z = pair[0],pair[2]
                sommething = x,y

return render_template("page.html", something=something)
f.close()
```

Comment: Загвоздка в том, что Вы постоянно перезаписываете переменную `sommething` и в ней остаётся только последнее значение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
with open("c.txt", 'r') as f:
    last3 = deque(f, 3)
    for line in last3:
            co.append(line.strip().split(','))
            sommething = tuple((pair[0],pair[2]) for pair in co)

return render_template("page.html", something=something)
f.close()
```

Comment: спасибо. данный вариант работает.  только как мне тогда отобразить лист без запятых. Вместо `('Маша', 'Иванова')`, чтобы было бы `Маша Иванова`на странице. Потому что в моем варианте не было запятых и скобок при отображении.

Comment: ' '.join(('Маша', 'Иванова'))

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_something(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        last3 = deque(f, 3)
        for line in last3:
            co.append(line.strip().split(','))
            for pair in co:
                x,y,z = pair[0],pair[2]
                yield x,y

render_template("page.html", something=list(get_something('c.txt')))
```